# Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png

Tags: php

I want to get the size of images but i have a warning problem 
   I have this code

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com');
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $file= $image->getAttribute('src');
  echo filesize($file);
}***
```

Comment: This is looking for image files on _your_ server, which don’t exist there. You would need to complete the relative image URLs used in that page to absolute ones first of all. (But then you could still not use `filesize`, because the HTTP wrapper does not support `stat` functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use following:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $file= $image->getAttribute('src');
    $img = get_headers($url . $file, 1);
    echo 'image size : ' . $img["Content-Length"];
}
```

- use `get_headers()` to fetch all the headers sent by the server in response to the HTTP request [php.net/get_headers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution for you - create a local temporary file and output the filesize. This is pretty raw. I'd highly recommend some sanity checks on this. But the general idea is to retrieve the file and perform your `filesize` check locally.

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com');
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $file= $image->getAttribute('src');
  file_put_contents('testing.tmp', file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/${file}"));
  echo filesize('testing.tmp');
}
```